# Python can't open text file (wrong mode)

Tags: python

I'm using PIL to process a wave image from audacity. I've made a version of this code which draws the fourier transform of this curve using matplotlib and it worked. Now I'm trying to get the coordinates of the points used to make the fourier transform in a text file instead of drawing the curve. I'm trying to open a new file with "a" mode which should create a new file and write inside it. However, I'm getting

```
  File "D:\Prog\Python\Fourier\fourier text.py", line 78, in <module>
    TXTfr = open('textF.txt','a')
  File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2624, in open
    raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'a'
```

I have tried using 'w' mode but it still doesn't work.

This is the part of the code used to write. I have closed the image file with `img.close()` the line above.

```py
TXTfr = open('textF.txt','a')
TXTa = open('textA.txt','a')
TXTfr.write('[')
for i in range(len(fi)):
    TXTfr.write(str(fi[i]))
TXTfr.write(']')

TXTa.write("[")
for i in range(len(sm)):
    TXTa.write(str(fi[sm]))
TXTa.write(']')
```

Thanks for reading and hoping someone will be able to help.

Comment: Your code is opening text files - it has nothing to do with PIL or that tag.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the error message is coming from `Image.py` tells you that the `open()` you are calling is not Python's built-in `open()` function, but the `open()` from `PIL`.  The `mode` accepted by PIL.Image.open() describes an image mode, not a mode for regular files, so that function is not what you want for writing regular files.

The question is how did this happen? One way would be if you accidentally did (for example)

```
from PIL.Image import *
```

That would replace Python's built-in `open()` with `PIL.Image.open()`.

You should edit the question to show what your `import` statements look like.

Comment: I used ```import PIL
from PIL.Image import *
from math import *
import cmath```
How can I use the open function from PIL for the image and the open from python for the textfile?

Comment: You could, but you would have to tell it which one you want to use... if you just say `open`, how could it "know"? Just do `from PIL import Image` and call `Image.open()` so it knows which one to use.